# what is the best source for server design patterns/best practices?

Tags: c, linux, design-patterns, pthreads, process

I've searched for a while for a good book which covers server designed patterns.  I'm looking for something along the lines of Gang of Four.

Concepts include:

-- Threaded vs Process vs combo based solutions
-- How to triage requests properly.  i.e. I expect only limited requests from any domain, so I may only allocate a certain number of workers per domain.
-- Worker timeouts
-- poll/select/epoll use cases
-- And those things I don't know!

Any suggestions please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Two very useful books:

- [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)
- [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683):

> The book Enterprise Integration
>   Patterns provides a consistent
>   vocabulary and visual notation to
>   describe large-scale integration
>   solutions across many implementation
>   technologies. It also explores in
>   detail the advantages and limitations
>   of asynchronous messaging
>   architectures. You will learn how to
>   design code that connects an
>   application to a messaging system, how
>   to route messages to the proper
>   destination and how to monitor the
>   health of a messaging system. The
>   patterns in the book are
>   technology-agnostic and come to life
>   with examples implemented in different
>   messaging technologies, such as SOAP,
>   JMS, MSMQ, .NET, TIBCO and other EAI
>   Tools.

Comment: +1 absolutely recommend this book.

Comment: I enjoyed _Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture_ more than its title would suggest. :) But I wouldn't really think of it as the place to learn how to write good Unix servers.

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949) is a fantastic resource for learning the details of Unix systems programming. It's extremely well-written (one of my favorite books in the English Language), the depth is excellent, and the focus on four common environments (at the time of publication) help ensure that it is well-rounded. It's not too badly out of date -- new features in newer operating systems may be fantastic for specific problems, but this book really covers the basics very well.

The downside, of course, is that APUE2nd misses out on some fantastic third-party tools such as [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/), which can make programming sockets-based servers significantly easier. (And automatically picks the 'best' of `select(2)`, `poll(2)`, `epoll(4)`, `kpoll`, and Windows event handling, for the platform.)

As for choosing between threads and processes, it comes down to: how much memory sharing do you want / need between tasks? If each process can run relatively isolated, processes provide better memory protection and no speed penalty. If processes need to interact with each other's objects, or objects 'owned' by a single thread, then threads provide better primitives for sharing data. (But many would argue that the shared memory of threads is an invitation to fun and exciting bugs. It Depends.)